# FIT SDK Example

Tags: ios, fit-protocol

I am developing a health/fitness application for iOS allows the user to export workouts as FIT files, for use with other fitness applications. The documentation on the sdk is very good, but has very limited implementation examples. Are there examples for how to export a workout (using workout step messages) either online, open source, or that someone can provide?

The part I am struggling with is how do I include multiple step duration types for the same time interval of a workout. Is there something I am not quite getting right with the documentation? Also, how can I include heart rate info without specifying above or below?